# gethostbyname() alternatives in c

Tags: c, networking, gethostbyname

I am currently doing a project on networking game where I need to design a game where maximum of 3 clients can connect to the server and the game is played between all the clients and server. I am using the "sockaddr_in" structure at both the server and client side.

In my game, anyone can become the server and the clients should give the correct IP address and port number to be able to connect to the server. When I hard code the values of the IP address of server and port number in "server_address.sin_addr.s_addr" and "server_address.sin_port" respectively the game works fine. But hard coded will not solve my problem of anyone being a server and asking the clients to enter the server's address and port number. So, I used "gethostbyname()" function call on the client's side. But it did not solve my problem. (may the reason is that behaviour of gethostbyname() when passed a numeric string is unspecified. (Source : [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyaddr.html)) .

Below is the code used by me at server side :

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;
/* open a socket */
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
    {
        err_ret = errno;
        return err_ret;
    }
    /* set initial values */
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    memset(&(serv_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
    /* bind address with socket */
    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) 
    {
        err_ret = errno;
        return err_ret;
    }
```

and at client side

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *to;
/* generate address */
if((to = gethostbyname(IP))==NULL) 
{
    err_ret = h_errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "gethostbyname() error...\n");
    return err_ret;
}
/* open a socket */
if((newfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
{
    err_ret = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "socket() error...\n");
    return err_ret;
}
/* set initial values */
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr, to->h_addr_list[0], to->h_length);
memset(&(serv_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
```

Can anyone here tell an efficient way to carry out the above process?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your problem that `gethostbyname(IP)` fails for a correct numerical address string? Or is your question  how to dynamically configure one host as a server and make its IP address known to the potential clients?

Comment: My problem is the first one you mentioned. Also, the second problem's solution can help me improve the game. Can you give a hint regarding the same?

Comment: So what does `IP` contain? What does `gethostbyname(IP)` return? How does it "not solve your problem"? Note that an error status is written to `h_errno`, not to `errno`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The "IP" address contains IPv4 address passed as a "char *". For example : "127.0.0.1" etc. `gethostbyname(IP)` returns `struct hostent *`. The reason it might not work is given the link attached with the question.

Comment: What I meant is a *concrete example* where your code fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getaddrinfo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) has superseded gethostbyname.  That should make it easier to create sockaddr_in structs from IP address strings.

Sample code to convert either a string in numeric form or as a hostname to a sockaddr_in.

```
struct addrinfo hints = {};
addrinfo* pResultList = NULL;
struct sockaddr_in addr = {};
char* hostname = "1.2.3.4";

hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
//  hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;  // if you know hostname is a numeric stirng, you can skip the DNS lookup by setting this flag

result = getaddrinfo(hostname , NULL, &hints, &pResultList);

if (result)
    memcpy(&addr, pResultList->ai_addr, sizeof(addr));

if (pResultList != NULL)
{
    ::freeaddrinfo(pResultList);
}
```

Comment: Someone downvoted.  Not sure why.  Perhaps he would like to comment about what he didn't like about the answer?

Comment: Probably because `inet_ntoa` is deprecated and has been for some time. `getaddrinfo` is what you should be using, not those antiquated functions.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - that's pretty lame reason to downvote given that I had originally cited both inet_pton and inet_aton as well.  inet_pton isn't always available on all platforms.  In any case, I had decided to update my answer to steer the OP to just using `getaddrinfo`. Perhaps you'll reconsider your vote.

Comment: Which headers files are required for using the above code as I am getting unknown type "addrinfo" in my code? I used these 3 headers from [this link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)

Comment: @likecs - Which platform are you on?  Windows, Mac,  or Unix/Linux ?

Comment: @likecs - if you are programming in C instead of C++, you may need to declare `struct addrinfo` instead of `addrinfo`. I updated my answer above.